# conditional query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure with many conditions but one of them depend of the value of one of my parameter.
At the moment I'm using if statement and duplicate query, I want to improve but I can't find other way. some idea how

MyStoreProcedure Code

```
If @paramstate = 'All'
    Select mytable.field1, mytable.field2, mytable.field3, mytable.field4,mytable.field5
    from mytable
    Where mytable.field6 is null
    and mytable.field1 is not null
Else
    Select mytable.field1, mytable.field2, mytable.field3, mytable.field4,mytable.field5
    from mytable
    Where mytable.field6 is null
    and mytable.field1 is not null
    and mytable.state = @paramstate 
End
```

how can I improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this removes the need for the if/else but beware that this **may not** be efficient

```
 Select mytable.field1, mytable.field2, mytable.field3, mytable.field4,mytable.field5
    from mytable
    Where mytable.field6 is null
    and mytable.field1 is not null
    and (mytable.state = @paramstate  or @paramstate = 'All')
```